# Multiple MAX in one Excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the formula on excel that will solve my problem.

I need to calculate X, which is equivalent to a percentage Y÷2 (and X has maximum and minimum values which depend on Y)

We have that if Y is less than 500, X represents 25% of Y. In this case, X must take a value between 5 and 125.

If Y is between 500 and 1000, X represents 20% of Y. In this case, X must take a value between 125 and 200.

If Y is greater than 1000, X represents 15% of Y. In this case, X must take a value between 200 and 400.

In order to find the value of X based on the value of Y, I first used this formula (omitting the max and min values)

```
Y=A2

=IF(A2<500; A2*0,125; IF(A2<=1000; A2*0,1; IF(A2>1000; A2*0,075)))
```

Now I tried to incorporate in my formula the min and max and that's where I'm stuck

For the first part of the problem (Y<500), I applied this formula:

```
=MAX((IF(A2<500;A2*0,125));5)
```

Ideally I would have realized this formula:

```
=MAX((IF(A2<500; A2*0,125));5) ; MAX((IF(A2<=1000; A2*0,1));125) ; MAX((IF(A2>1000; A2*0,075));200)
```

But since I can't do it (Excel won't let me), would you have any alternatives to offer me?

Comment: What is your excel version? Check that your excel have `MAXIFS()` function or not. Post some sample data and expected output then explain logic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to determine the percentage based on the value but set a minimum?

```
=IF(A2<500,MAX(A2*0.125,5),IF(A2<=1000,MAX(A2*0.1,125),MAX(A2*0.075,200)))
```